# Pulldown choice to return the integer (the index) rather than the string using tcl in Nuke

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

what is the similar code of python knob.getValue() in tcl? i want to get the value of a pulldown knob, but i want to get the index rather than than string.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The current index can be retrieved with the `current` method:

```
pack [ttk::combobox .c -values {a b c d e} -state readonly]

# Later, after something is selected...
puts "[.c get] is the current value, [.c current] is the current index"
# Example output: c is the current value, 2 is the current index
```

Note that in `normal` mode, user-supplied values are allowed as well as those in the drop-down list. In that case, the `current` method will report `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

3 years late but for future reference :

`[numvalue knob_name]` in TCL will return the index of the pulldown choice menu selected item as an integer.

```
[value Keylight1.show] #--> Final Result
[numvalue Keylight1.show] #--> 8
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no method to do this in Tk.

You have to use a mega-widget to implement this functionality:

https://sourceforge.net/p/tcl-combobox-enhanced/code/ci/default/tree/